# Ошибка добавления элемента в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

есть код:

```
<script>
    function MyObject(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    var arr = new Array();
    var my = new MyObject();

    my.name = "1";
    arr.push(my);

    my.name = "2";
    arr.push(my);

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }   
</script>
```

в лог падает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а ожидалось что в массив добавятся разные объекты с именами 1 и 2. В чем причина такого поведения и как исправить?

Comment: "разные объекты" - почему? Объектная переменная это ссылка (reference) на объект; меняя его свойства, Вы не создаете новых объектов.

Comment: @Igor, все осознал свою ошибку. это переход с языка С++ сказывается.

Comment: PS я думал что в массив копия попадает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В JavaScript все объекты присваиваются и передаются по ссылке. Как следствие, выполняя:

```
arr.push(my);
```

вы добавляете не объект, а *ссылку* на него. Все последующие изменения объекта, лежащего в переменной `my` отразятся и на том объекте, что уже лежит в массиве. Так работают ссылочные типы данных.